# Why Kendo datasource functions is not called?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am trying to bind returned data from datasource to grid but the problem is that non of my data source functions is called...

```
transactionHistoryGridDS: new kendo.data.DataSource({
    error: function () {
        alert("erroe")
    },
    complete: function () {
        alert("completed")
    },
    success: function () {
        alert("success");
    },
    transport: {
        read: {
            dataType: "json",
            type: 'POST',
            url: args.TransactionHistoryUrl,
            data: {
                id: function () {return vm.transactionHistoryParams.id },
                originBranch: function () {return vm.transactionHistoryParams.originBranch },
                take: function () {return vm.transactionHistoryParams.take },
                skip: function () {return vm.transactionHistoryParams.skip }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            parse: function (data) {
                alert("hey...")
                return data;
            },
            data: "data",
            total: "total",
        },
        pageSize: 20,
        serverPaging: false
    }
}),
```

When i call read datasource through below code

```
 vm.transactionHistoryGridDS.read();
```

Ajax request is called and data successfully returned from the server,but non of the functions including `success` and `error` and `complete` and `parse` is called
and consequently, data is not bind to the grid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see some bugs that need to be fixed before your grid will work.

First of all, `schema`, `pageSize`, `serverPaging` is on wrong indent level, it should be on same level as `transport` not inside it.

```
transport: {...},
schema: {...},
serverPaging: ...,
pageSize: ...
```

Every grid should have dataSource property, read will be called automatically and data will be populated, you dont need to set data to grid or call `read()` function:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    dataSource: {
        transport: {
            read: {...}
        }
    }
});
```

In your case I assume vm is a grid so you need to set `dataSource:transactionHistoryGridDS,` check example links below

If you need to send data with request use `parameterMap`:

```
$('#grid').kendoGrid({
    resizable: true,
    filterable: true,
    sortable: true,
    pageable: {
        pageSize: 10,
        refresh: true,
        pageSizes: [5, 10, 20, 100, 500, 1000]
    },
    dataSource: {
        pageSize: 10,
        serverPaging: true,
        serverFiltering: true,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: 'url',
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                contentType: 'application/json'
            },
            update: {...},
            destroy: {...},
            parameterMap(data, type) {
                switch (type) {
                    case 'read':
                        let request = {};
                        request.page = data.page - 1;
                        request.page_size = data.pageSize;
                        request.sort = data.sort;
                        request.filter = data.filter;

                        return JSON.stringify(request);
                    case 'destroy':
                        return kendo.stringify(data);
                    default:
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

There is two way of geting data from kendo `dataSource` request, first one it with `complete` function that is called when request and response is finished. The second is promise on every dataSource request.

First example: [complete call](https://dojo.telerik.com/iqUKUYuq)

Second example: [promise call](https://dojo.telerik.com/oRIXUpUg)